# Ubuntu 18.04 Touchpad randomly jumps

Tags: touchpad, dell, 18.04

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 (3558). Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu, there have been problems where the touch-pad randomly jumps when using it. For example I could be scrolling up and the cursor would instantly jump to the top at the slightest touch. I lowered sensitivity in settings but that doesn't seem to help. I read a solution online where the touch-pad sensitivity seems to be fixed but the tap-and-click function doesn't work. I don't want to sacrifice the tap-click function for sensitivity. Here are the results of xinput:

[image]

Comment: I've had jumpy touchpad issues on my HP and MSI laptops for a long time, yet it works fine in Windows.  I gave up trying to solve it and found it much easier to just disable the touchpad and use a mouse.  I'm interested to see if a working solution presents itself.

Answer (score 1):

I observe the behavior persists only when my laptop is plugged in. Found that one when I was looking through this [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2152733).

One temporary hack is by placing your hand on the keyboard or any 
metal part of your laptop to ground it.

Comment: To me it happens even if the laptop is unplugged (XPS 13 here). Any other suggestions?